# Use windows snip and sketch clipboard temp image in cmd

Tags: powershell, batch-file, imagemagick, screen-capture

So i'm trying to use the current clipboard file when using snip and sketch in windows 10 in a imagemagick .bat process which converts them to icons, it seems to save to the directy,

`AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`

But its 3 files,a .json,thumbnail, and then the actual picture. The two pngs dont have any way to differenciate themselves, the file sizes and time made and resolution and name all seem to be random so i cant pull them from that folder, it also seems to save every single snip ever so its a big mess.

Part of the problem i think is that it doesnt appear in the paste clipboard even tho it does exist somewhere because you can paste directly into word docs or discord and it recognises it.

The other thing i've tried is getting the paste.exe from c3scripts.com which only seems to work with text outputting to a .txt file.

I've tried powershell using `Get-Clipboard` command, which also only works with text.

Does anyone know how to pull this file from the clipboard into something usable in cmd so i can add it to the .bat or if theres another program enterierly that could snip the screen more efficinetly.

TLDR: need way to crop and screencap and save file with least amount of steps possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Get-clipboard's -format switch in Powershell:

```
# Verify if clipboard has image and if it has then save it
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$clipboard = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetDataObject() 
if ($clipboard.ContainsImage()) {
  $img = get-clipboard -format image 
  $img.save("FilePath")
}
```